# coloring tree with minimum sum of colors

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

The problem is to color tree vertices with natural numbers such that sum of numbers(colors) assigned to vertices be minimum.

Is number of colors to do that bounded?

Comment: Are you missing something from your requirements here? Do all vertices need a unique number, or should adjacent vertices not have the same number perhaps?

Comment: Adjacent vertices should be colored with different numbers.

Comment: How do you tell which vertices (nodes?) are adjacent to one another? Is it just that parents are adjacent to their children?

Comment: Hmm. At first I thought this was the famous 4 color problem [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem]. However, that applies to general graphs. If you have a tree then won't 2 colors be enough, you just alternate each "layer" in the tree?

Comment: @Kevin: In a tree nodes with edge between them are considered adjacent, so in a rooted tree a parent and it's child are adjacent to each other.

Comment: @SteveHaigh: 2 color are enough just to color a tree, but I want the sum of numbers(colors) of vertices can be minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think 3 colors are enough to do that. How to prove it?

It's not. Describe a rooted tree algebraically as follows. `V` is a one-node tree. `E(t1, t2)` is a tree consisting of `t1` and `t2` and an edge from `t1`'s root to `t2`'s root, rooted at `t2`'s root. The following tree `t3` requires four colors to attain the minimum, 156.

```
t3 = E(t2, E(t2, E(t2, E(t2, t2))))
t2 = E(t1, E(t1, E(t1, E(t1, t1))))
t1 = E(t0, E(t0, E(t0, E(t0, t0))))
t0 = V
```

Based on some experimentation, I <strike>would conjecture</strike> can prove that this construction generalizes and thus that no fixed number of colors suffices to attain the minimum for all trees.

**Theorem** For all  d ≥ k ≥ 3, the following inductively constructed tree T(d, k) requires at least k colors. T(d, 1) is the one-vertex tree. For i > 1, T(d, i) is the tree with d leaves attached to each vertex of T(d, i - 1).

**Proof** By induction on k. The base case k = 3 is essentially your example where 3 colors are necessary for optimality. For k > 3, consider a coloring of T(d, k) that uses only k - 1 colors. We show how to use color k to improve it. If some internal vertex has color 1, then we improve by changing its color to k and changing the colors of its d > k - 1 adjacent leaves to 1. If no interval vertex has color 1, and some leaf has color other than 1, change the leaf to 1. If we haven't improved yet, all leaves have color 1 and all interval vertices have color > 1. Removing all the leaves and decrementing the labels, we have a coloring of T(d, k - 1), which we can improve by inductive hypothesis.

---

```
data Tree = V | E Tree Tree
    deriving (Eq, Show)

otherMinimums [x, y] = [y, x]
otherMinimums (x:xs) = minimum xs : map (min x) (otherMinimums xs)

color m V = [1..m]
color m (E t1 t2) = let
    c1 = color m t1
    c2 = color m t2 in
    zipWith (+) (otherMinimums c1) c2

t3 = E t2 $ E t2 $ E t2 $ E t2 $ t2
t2 = E t1 $ E t1 $ E t1 $ E t1 $ t1
t1 = E t0 $ E t0 $ E t0 $ E t0 $ t0
t0 = V
```

Results:

```
> color 3 t3
[157,158,163]
> color 4 t3
[157,158,159,156]
```

Comment: It's definitely at most 156 for 4 colors. Construct the coloring as follows: the label of the single vertex in `t0` is 1, the labels in `ti` are, for each of five copies of `ti-1`, the same colors, except the root has to be incremented by one. The recurrence is T(0) = 1; T(i) = 5 * T(i-1) + 1; so T(0) = 1, T(1) = 6, T(2) = 31, T(3) = 156.

Answer (score 2):

First, 2 colors is enough for any tree. To prove that, you can just color the tree level by level in alternate colors.

Second, coloring level by level is the only valid method of 2-coloring. It can be proved by induction on the levels. Fix the color of the root node. Then all its children should have the different color, children of the children — first color, and so on.

Third, to choose the optimal coloring, just check the two possible layouts: when the root node has the color `0`, and when it has the color `1`, respectively.

Comment: sometimes adding a third color reduces the sum.

Answer (score 0):

For a tree, you can use only 2 colors : one for for nodes with odd depth and a second color for nodes with even depth.

EDIT:
The previous answer was wrong because I didn't understand the problem.

As shown by Wobble, the number of colors needed is not bounded.

Comment: sometimes adding a third color reduces the sum.

Comment: @a-z Can you please provide an example of such a case?

Comment: edge list{1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-5, 5-6, 5-7, 5-8}, color vertex 1 with 3, vertex 5 with 2 and the others with 1.

Comment: The problem is to find a maximum independent set for the color 1, then a maximum independent set for the color 2, …

Answer (score 0):

Number of colours to minimise sum for a tree with n nodes is bounded as O(logn)

This was covered by E. Kubicka in her 1989 paper
http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=75430